# How to refresh jQuery Datatable with webmethod data source?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, datatables

I have a datatable that I have initialized by

```
 function getData()
        {
               $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'players.aspx/getPlayerList',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var listData = eval(data.d);


                    $('#test').DataTable({
                        data: listData
                         ,
                        "columns": [
                            { "data": "id" },
                            { "data": "playername" },
                            { "data": "points" },
                            { "data": "steals" },
                            { "data": "blocks" },
                            { "data": "assists" },
                            { "data": "mpg" },
                            { "data": "shootingpercentage" },
                            { "data": "threepointpercentage" }
                        ]
                    });




                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('failure');
                }
            });
        }
```

With this webmethod

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]        
        public static object getPlayerList()
        {
            NBAPlayerRepository players = new NBAPlayerRepository();
            DataTable dt = players.GetAll();
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
            return json;            
        }
```

How would I update the datatable when I add new rows of data?

I know about ajax.reload, but I'm not sure that works here because I'm using a Webmethod to load the table and not a .json file. Is there another way besides the reload that may work better for my implementation?

Comment: How are you adding new rows? Directly through DataTables? To the `NBAPlayerRepository`? Also, _when_ will you be adding these new rows? While the page is running? Ajax.reload will re-call the webmethod.

Comment: No, I have a form for adding the data which uses ajax and a webmethod to create a new player and add it to the sqlite database and then pull the new data back into a json which is returned by ajax. Yes while the page is running. So something like   $('#test').DataTable.ajax.reload ? or how would I format that? I think you helped me out earlier haha.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer. Hang tight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've interpreted your comments correctly, you are saying that though the data is updated on another page with ajax, the data in the database is also updated. This means that if you re-call the webmethod, you will get the updated data (this answer relies on that being true).

The issue with that is that you are constructing your DataTable in the success callback of the ajax call. I'd recommend switching the format of your code to make the ajax an option of the DataTable, which will facilitate changing the data much better. If you aren't willing/able to make this change, leave a comment and I'll try to rework the solution to work the other way.

If you can make that change, you can just call ajax reload after the data has been updated to the database. The way to do that is as follows:

```
var table =  $('#test').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'players.aspx/getPlayerList',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataSrc: 'data'
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "id" },
        { "data": "playername" },
        { "data": "points" },
        { "data": "steals" },
        { "data": "blocks" },
        { "data": "assists" },
        { "data": "mpg" },
        { "data": "shootingpercentage" },
        { "data": "threepointpercentage" }
    ]
});
```

Then, after you do your updating of the data, simply call `table.ajax.reload();` and the data will be reloaded.

Note: see [this page](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) for the documentation for the `ajax` option to dataTables if you want to specify more options.

Answer (score 0):

this will add new rows to grid when you added them without getting whole list from database.

```
var t = $('#test').DataTable();

$('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
   t.row.add(["id","playername","points","steals","blocks","assists","mpg","shootingpercentage","threepointpercentage"]).draw( false );
});
```

or you can clear whatever your grid have and reload from db.

```
$('#table').dataTable().fnClearTable();
$('#table').dataTable().fnAddData(listData);
```

Comment: I tried the second method you listed, but I get an error about non table node initalization. I am using datatables 1.10 if that makes a difference.

Comment: @hereswilson, `table.clear().draw()` will do it (if `table` is the 1.10.x instance initialised with `DataTable()`)

Comment: @davidkonrad instead of the fnClearTable(); or what do you mean?